# Pull Request without Repository Access

Tags: git, repository, pull-request

I have cloned   http://git.savannah.gnu.org/r/gpsd.git repository.I also created new local branch. Now I have found one bug in any file i.e maintainers.txt  and edited it.

I did git commit .
But when I run git push ..It ask to set it upstream stream.
But when I did

**fatal: unable to access 'http://git.savannah.gnu.org/r/gpsd.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403**

I have faced this error.I know I dont have access to that repo so that happened .So how to work and generate pull request if we dont have access on the repository.?
Can I create repo with same content on my github ? If yes How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how to work and generate pull request if we dont have access on the repository.?

*Pull requests* are not git things, they are git-hosting service capabilities (i.e. GitHub, Bitbucket, Visual Studio Online, etc.).  So to answer your question, you would have to find out if a pull request is even **possible** with your git-hosting service.  Judging by what I see when I navigate to that URI, it doesn't appear as though pull requests are possible or at the very least not straight-forward.

> Can I create repo with same content on my github ? If yes How?

Yes, absolutely.  All you need to do is create a new repo on GitHub, and then push your local repository to GitHub after you add the GitHub repo as a `remote`.  [This entire process is documented thoroughly on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/).

Comment: git remote add punit http://git.savannah.gnu.org/r/gpsd.git/   I have added remote repo and did   "git push punit master "  But It gives me error fatal: unable to access 'http://git.savannah.gnu.org/r/gpsd.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: @punitvara That's because you don't have permissions to push to that remote repo.  I thought you wanted to push to GitHub?

Comment: Exactly  I have added commit on my local branch and I want to submit the developer ..What should I do ?